# I need to color the row with different color based on the row count

Tags: vba, excel

```
Dim WorkRng As Range
Dim r As Range, rC As Range
Dim j, k As Long
Dim SplitRow As Integer

xTitleId = "KutoolsforExcel"

Set WorkRng = Application.Selection

Set WorkRng = Application.InputBox("Range", xTitleId, WorkRng.Address, Type:=8)
Set r = Nothing
Set rC = Nothing

j = 0
k = 0

Set r = WorkRng
For Each rC In r
    j = j + 1
    If j = r.Count Then Exit For
Next rC

SplitRow = Application.InputBox("Split Row Num", xTitleId, 5, Type:=1)

k = j / SplitRow
```

This my code , Where it will count the rows and the row count will be divide with the input value ! but what i want to do is ,if the row count is 8 and the input value is 2 the result will be 4 , so the first 4 rows should be in a color and next four row should be in another color !!
to make it clear i need to color the rows with the input i give which will divide the sum of the rows and with the answer the rows need to be colored .
Kindle help me with this !!!

Comment: Note that `Dim j, k As Long` defines `k As Long` but `j As Variant`. You need to specify a type for **every** variable: `Dim j As Long, k As Long`.

Comment: j can just be rc.rows.count

Comment: Look at using a `step` in a `loop` and the `offset` and/or `resize` using the rows to colour count

Comment: okay thank you but still i want to color the rows with different color equally to the sum of the rows !! can you help me with that ?

Comment: yep , i have tried the offset and resize but it only gives me the count and the selection , i need to color the row equally like , if there are 6 rows and the input given by me is 3 which divides and the answer is 2 , first 2 rows should be in a color and the second set of 2 rows in an another color and the third set of 2 rows be in another color !!

Comment: Changing the colour of a range is done with `Range.Interior.Color`, is that what you're asking?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this - loop until i is equal to the available rows in the selected range divided by the `SplitRow`.

Note that `FormatRange` cannot hold a decimal count (cannot count 4.5 rows). `FormatRange` will always be converted to a whole number so you may want to control for this or you may get unwanted results when your division does not yield a whole number.

```
Sub test()

Dim MyCell As Range, i As Long

Dim SelectedRange As Range
Set SelectedRange = Application.InputBox("Select Range", Type:=8)

Dim SplitRow As Long
SplitRow = Application.InputBox("Split Row Num", Type:=1)

Dim FormatRange As Long
FormatRange = SelectedRange.Rows.Count / SplitRow

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each MyCell In SelectedRange
        If i < FormatRange Then
            MyCell.Interior.Color = vbRed
            i = i + 1
        Else
            MyCell.Interior.Color = vbYellow
        End If
    Next MyCell
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for that ,

Comment: but can you modify it like , i gave the range as 8 and the split row as 2 so it color the first four rows and leave the next four rows . my need is total eight rows first 4 rows should be in a color and another 4 rows should be in different color !

Comment: can you help on that ?

Comment: No , i don't have problem in coloring , see i will make it clear , i am giving the range has 4 rows and the split count as 2 , the code colors the first 2 rows only !!! i need to color the balance 2 rows in different color !!!? can anyone understand my problem ?

Comment: You want to color your range 2 different colors? So the first half Red and second half blue? Is that what you are asking for?

Comment: You want to color your range 2 different colors? So the first half Red and second half blue? Is that what you are asking for?  ---  yes this is what i need !!!

Comment: adding to the above comment 2 half is not constant it will change according to the value given , what if i get 3 set or more than that , if my range as more than 3 half then its should be 3 different color , what i should do then ?

Comment: using a input box in the sense the value will change !! that's what i am trying to say, no matter how my set of half occurs vb should color it differently  , this is my need !

Comment: update your questions with photos that show before and after results with the inputs. Show varying inputs to get your **full** point across. Let me know when that is done and I will give this one more edit

Comment: What is the max number for your Split?

Comment: it change according to the need brother !! wait i ll post the question with a screen shot for your reference ! after seeing that help me .

Comment: i have posted the updated question with reference kindly see it !